# Fully qualified name of Spymemcached for JCache

Tags: java, spring, caching, memcached

We are trying to implement JCache in such a way as we can easily swap any JSR-107 compliant cache provider. We are using Spring and our `CachingProvider` Bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
public CachingProvider cachingProvider() {
    CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider(env.getProperty("jcache.provider.fullyQualifiedName"));
    return cachingProvider;
}
```

This allows us to swap in and out any compliant cache we would like by adding the fully qualified name in our properties file and of course adding the jar to the classpath. Currently for implementing Hazelcast our config file looks like this:

```
jcache.provider.fullyQualifiedName=com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider
```

However, I would like to implement spymemcached for this yet I am unable to find the fully qualified name for this (or any other JSR-107 compliant implementation).

So my question is does anyone out there know the fully qualified name for Spymemchaced or any other JSR-107 compliant cache providers? I've googled and googled yet have been unable to come up with anything.

Comment: A fully compliant memcached provider is not possible due to memcached not supporting iteration. EntryProcessors are harder but could be emulated using a distributed lock. There are ad hoc providers, like [this one](https://github.com/linux-china/spymemcached-jcache). The qualified name of a provider is stored in the jar's `META-INF/services/javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to switch your caching provider by adding a different jar, the best answer is: Just do it! You don't need any extra configuration for this.

You can use only `Caching.getCachingProvider()`. This will return the JSR107 compatible caching provider that you added to your application (that is in the classpath). Internally it is using the service provider interface mechanism, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html

It gets more complicated, when you want to use different caching providers within one application **at the same time**. You can peek the spi file in the jar file, as Ben suggested in his comment, or, you can iterate them via `Caching.getCachingProviders()`. To get the fully qualified name print the class names with `getClass().getName()`.

Comment: That was my original understanding also but that does not seem to work. If I replace with your example I get this error: Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: No CachingProviders have been configured
        at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:381)
        at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:351)
        at javax.cache.Caching.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:142)

Comment: Ok, I decided to test this way again. I don't know but this time it is working!

Comment: Perfect. BTW: Your problem smells a little like a class loading issue.

Comment: Yea, I probably made a change, didn't push it... something weird like that. Still learning this and making lots of changes and testing.